# Print to network printer from PHP

Tags: php, printing

What is the best approach for printing (an existing pdf, in my case) to a LAN printer directly from php?  So far I have been unsuccessful in getting anything to work, but I'm not sure what direction to further pursue.  I am running Apache on Windows SBS 2008, PHP 5.3.9.

Approaches I know of so far:

- shell_exec()
- phpprintipp - this seems like the best approach to me if I could get it to work
- php_printer.dll - no **current** dll exists

It seems like this should be a simple task that has a widely accepted approach, but so far I'm not finding it.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is possible in your case, but to avoid all sorts of problems with trying to go from webserver to printer, we are using the FTP mode of the printers to accomplish this. We just dump the pdf on the ftp-spool thingy the printer itself has, and you're done (once you're able to convert everything to PDF obviously). Only usefull if your printer supports this, so that's why you're getting a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: Use `php_printer.dll`.  What's wrong with it?  Why isn't it working for you?  Don't reinvent the wheel by talking directly to IP printers.

Comment: Why not let the OS handle the printer? What happens if you script is trying to hit that 'default printer' and the network (or route to the printer) is unavailable?

Comment: @Brad - I can successfully connect to a printer, and then use fopen/fread to get the pdf contents, also with no errors.  If I change the PRINTER_MODE to RAW I get no errors, but nothing happens.  If I don't change the printer mode, I get 15 pages of garbage.  In searching, I've seen that there can be some problems when Apache is running as the SYSTEM user, but I am running Apache as a different user with admin privileges, so that shouldn't be a problem here.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tough nut to crack. I've had my own adventures in Windows printing from Ruby and came up with a few potential solutions that work by invoking an external command, which in PHP-land is `system()` or `exec()` (don't forget `escapeshellcmd()`/`escapeshellarg()`—they tend to make this stuff easier, especially on Windows). All of them assume Windows knows about the printer and it can be referenced by name.

1. You can literally just redirect the file to the networked printer, e.g.:

   ```
   copy /b \path\to\filename.pdf > \\Printer_Machine\Printer_Queue
   ```

   The `/b` switch specifies a binary file, but I'm 80% sure it's not strictly now,
   in 2012.
2. You can try the `print` command:

   ```
   print /d:\\Printer_Machine\Printer_Queue \path\to\filename.pdf
   ```

   `\d` stands for "device." I haven't actually tried this one and I'm not sure if it
   works with PDF or only, owing to its DOS origins, text files.
3. Install Adobe Reader and use its command line facilities:

   ```
   AcroRd32.exe /t \path\to\filename.pdf "Printer Name" "Driver Name" "Port Name"
   ```

   I'm not sure if your server environment can accommodate Reader but this is the
   solution I've been most successful with. You can find
   [documentation here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acrobat_SDK_developer_faq.pdf#page=24)
   (PDF, pg. 24). `Printer Name` and `Driver Name` should match exactly what you see in the 
   printer's properties in Control Panel. `Port_Name` can usually be omitted, I think.
4. Print using [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/). I've never tried this on
   Windows but the
   [documentation is here](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Install.htm#General_Windows) 
   and there's
   [more info here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/8.00/Devices.htm#Win). The
   command goes something like this:

   ```
   gswin32.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%Printer Name" \path\to\filename.pdf
   ```

   `mswinpr2` refers to Windows' own print drivers (see the second link above),
   "`%printer%`" is literal and required and "`Printer Name`" should, again, match the
   printer's name from Control Panel exactly. Ghostscript has many, many options and
   you'll likely have to spend some time configuring them.

Finally, a general tip: You can register a network printer with a device name with the [`net use`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) command e.g.:

```
C:\> net use LPT2 \\Printer_Machine\Printer_Queue /persistent:yes
```

This *should* let you use `LPT2` or `LPT2:` in place of `\\Printer_...` with most commands.

I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Option 1 (copy) did cause the printer to print, but it was only a sheet that says "1 file(s) copied." and did not print my pdf.  With option 2 (print) I always get an "Unable to initialize device 'printer'".  With option 3 (Adobe Reader) I was able to successfully print from the command prompt on the server, but get nothing when running from PHP.  I echoed the line I am passing to exec, and it matches exactly what I input manually, but nothing happens.  Any thoughts on any of that?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a path issue, either to the PDF file or to the executable; what was the output from AcroRd32.exe when you ran it with `exec()`?

Comment: Tim, did you send a `control+z` (EOF) to your printer after copy?

Comment: @Jordan: I don't get any result.  If I supply an output variable, it returns an empty array ( array(0) { } ).

Comment: Hmm. Is there any output when you run it from the command line? You could try some of the other options in the Reader docs to see if you can e.g. open Reader with `exec()`.

Comment: @Jordan: This is what I'm passing to exec() (as echoed when the script is run): "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "\\CCASERVER\Data\CCA Proposals\test.pdf" "bizhubC252" "KONICA MINOLTAC252/C252P VXL" When I use that exact same thing in the command prompt, it works.  Should it look differently from php?  I don't get any output from the command prompt, but nor can I just open Reader through php.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this works for all printers but this gets the job done sending ZPL files to a Zebra label printer:

```
<?php 
if(($conn = fsockopen('192.168.10.112',9100,$errno,$errstr))===false){
    echo 'Connection Failed' . $errno . $errstr;
}

$data = <<<HERE
    ^XA
    ^FT50,200
    ^A0N,200,200^FDTEST^FS
    ^FT50,500
    ^A0N,200,200^FDZebra Printer^FS
    ^XZ
HERE;

#send request
$fput = fputs($conn, $data, strlen($data));

#close the connection
fclose($conn);
?>
```